# How to build a chrome extension that can attach a component in webpage similar to octotree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have found out 2 possible ways:

1. `Popup` - It helps in creating a **UI** but specific to the **toolbar**.
2. `Content Script` - It helps in **injecting** code but cannot inject a **react app** into the webpage.

**But none of these are relevant. Octotree attaches its application into the webpage. How is that done?**

How can I build a chrome extension which can have a **react component** into the **webpage**?

Comment: The most secure method is to [run it inside an iframe](https://itnext.io/create-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-using-inject-page-strategy-137650de1f39#6186).

Comment: I want to build an extension that should display a button on the bottom of the screen and when clicked should open a react component.